# Replacing Relative Links with External Links in PHP String

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I am working with an editor that works purely with internal relative links for files which is great for 99% of what I use it for.

However, I am also using it to insert links to files within an email body and relative links don't cut the mustard.

Instead of modifying the editor, I would like to search the string from the editor and replace the relative links with external links as shown below

Replace

```
files/something.pdf
```

With

```
https://www.someurl.com/files/something.pdf
```

I have come up with the following but I am wondering if there is a better / more efficient way to do it with PHP

```
<?php
$string = '<a href="files/something.pdf">A link</a>, some other text, <a href="files/somethingelse.pdf">A different link</a>';

preg_match_all('/<a[^>]+href=([\'"])(?<href>.+?)\1[^>]*>/i', $string, $result);

if (!empty($result)) {
    // Found a link.
    $baseUrl = 'https://www.someurl.com';
    $newUrls = array();
    $newString = '';

    foreach($result['href'] as $url) {
        $newUrls[] = $baseUrl . '/' . $url;
    }

    $newString = str_replace($result['href'], $newUrls, $string);

    echo $newString;
}
?>
```

Many thanks

Lee

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `preg_replace` to replace all the occurrences of files starting URLs inside double quotes:

```
$string = '<a href="files/something.pdf">A link</a>, some other text, <a href="files/somethingelse.pdf">A different link</a>';

$string = preg_replace('/"(files.*?)"/', '"https://www.someurl.com/$1"', $string);
```

The result would be:

```
<a href="https://www.someurl.com/files/something.pdf">A link</a>, some other text, <a href="https://www.someurl.com/files/somethingelse.pdf">A different link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You really should use DOMdocument for such job, but if you want to use a regex, this one does the job:

```
$string = '<a some_attribute href="files/something.pdf" class="abc">A link</a>, some other text, <a class="def" href="files/somethingelse.pdf" attr="xyz">A different link</a>';
$baseUrl = 'https://www.someurl.com';
$newString = preg_replace('/(<a[^>]+href=([\'"]))(.+?)\2/i', "$1$baseUrl/$3$2", $string);
echo $newString,"\n";
```

**Output:**

```
<a some_attribute href="https://www.someurl.comfiles/something.pdf" class="abc">A link</a>, some other text, <a class="def" href="https://www.someurl.com/files/somethingelse.pdf" attr="xyz">A different link</a>
```